# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRow' of undefined

Tags: protractor, jasmine-node, exceljs

Tried with 
cellValue= worksheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).value;

and 
cellValue=console.log(worksheet.getCell('A1'))

please find below my code :

```
cellread2=function(){
        var Excel; 
        var filePath = path.resolve(__dirname,'E:/excel.xlsx');
         if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
                    Excel = require('C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs'); 
         }
        var wb = new Excel.Workbook();
        console.log(wb);
        wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath);
        var worksheet = wb.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
        //cellValue= worksheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).value;//Error :TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRow' of undefined
        cellValue=console.log(worksheet.getCell('A1'))// TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCell' of undefined
         console.log(cellValue);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the existing library code. If you want to make it work you will have to make few changes in the existing code in file `AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exceljs\dist\es5\xlsx\xform\sheet\worksheet-xform.js`. Replace the code at line 284 with the following :

```
if (drawing.anchors && drawing.anchors.length > 0) {
        drawing.anchors.forEach(function (anchor) {              
          if (anchor.medium && anchor.range) {
            var image = {
              type: 'image',
              imageId: anchor.medium.index,
              range: anchor.range
            };
            model.media.push(image);
          }
        });
      }
```

And as for the code for reading the file use the following code.

**Note: I installed exceljs library globally and I am using version 4.6.1**

```
var path = require('path');
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var cellread2 = function () {
  var filePath = path.resolve('E:', 'excel.xlsx');
  var wb = new Excel.Workbook();
  wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function (data) {
    var worksheet = wb.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
    var cellValue = worksheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).value;
    console.log('cellValue', cellValue);
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
}
cellread2();
```

Answer (score 0):

It may occurs due to objects are mapped into the excel sheet instead of textual data.

Please create another excel sheet and check it again will resolve this issue.'

Sample code to read excel sheet using node.js is given below,

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');

var wb = new Excel.Workbook();
var path = require('path');
var filePath = path.resolve(__dirname,'sample.xlsx');

wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function(){

    var sh = wb.getWorksheet("Sheet1");

    sh.getRow(1).getCell(2).value = 32;
    wb.xlsx.writeFile("sample2.xlsx");
    console.log("Row-3 | Cell-2 - "+sh.getRow(3).getCell(2).value);

    console.log(sh.rowCount);
    //Get all the rows data [1st and 2nd column]
    for (i = 1; i <= sh.rowCount; i++) {
        console.log(sh.getRow(i).getCell(1).value);
        console.log(sh.getRow(i).getCell(2).value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the sheet name did not match with 'Sheet1', since I was modifying an existing excel file. Replacing the sheet name resolved the issue.